# CakePHP - Iterate through variable passed from Controller to View by using plain query

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am passing following variable `tagsCount` from my Controller to View:

```
$this->set('tagsCounts', $this->Tag->query('
    (
        SELECT
            t.id, t.sk_name, 0 AS count
        FROM
            tags t
        WHERE
            t.id NOT IN (
                SELECT tag_id
                FROM   video_tags vt
            )
    )
    UNION
    (
        SELECT
            t.id, t.sk_name, COUNT( * ) as count
        FROM
            videos v
            JOIN
                video_tags vt ON ( v.id = vt.video_id )
            JOIN
                tags t ON ( t.id = vt.tag_id ) 
        GROUP BY
            t.id
        ORDER BY
            COUNT( * ) asc
    )'
));
```

And in View I want to iterate trough this variable. I am using this code:

```
<?php for($z = 0; $z < sizeof($tagsCounts); $z++): ?>
    <?php echo $tags[$z]['Tag']['count'];?>
    <br>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

But it causes this error:

> Strict Standards: Non-static method String::insert() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /storage/hotweb/admin.porner.sk/cake/libs/debugger.php on line 673

and also

> Notice (8): Undefined index: count [APP/views/tags/index.ctp, line 20]

Could you please help me how to iterate through this variable and print only column called "count"?

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version and tag your question accordingly! ps. why aren't you using the CakePHP ORM and avoid such weird queries, that would save you a lot of trouble?

Comment: I am using version 1.3.8. And I am hardquerrying this model, because it was quite difficult select for me and I did not know how to use ORM to retrieve this data.

Comment: can you paste var_dump($tags) here ?